# read in distribution vector from excel file

Tags: r, xlsx

I have an excel datasheet which contains a distribution vector for one variable. I wonder how to read in this xlsx-file and represent it as a table object in R?

[image: distribution vector]

Comment: What did you try? Which Excel-reading packages did not perform well for you? What did `system.time()` report for each method?

Comment: If you want speed, `readxl` and `openxlsx` are probably the best packages.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean 'speed'. I just wonder how to get from a data.frame object where each category is represented as variable (which is how the object is represented after reading it in) to a 'table'-object where each column is a category from one variable.

Comment: I found a solution:

After reading in the single row data frame I converted it to a numeric vector and then added names to it to get a named numeric vector:

numeric_vector <- as.numeric(as.matrix(df))
names(numeric_vector) <- names(df)

But if anyone has a more elegant solution, I am still open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `tidyr` package that results in a data frame with two columns: the category identifiers and the data values. I recreated the data and read it with `read.csv()` but the same approach works with any of the packages used to read Excel files, such as `readxl`, `openxlsx`, or `xlsx`.

```
library(tidyr)
rawData <- "11,50,2,7,23,10"
colNames <- c("Category 1","Category 2","Category 3","Category 4","Category 5","Category 6")

data <- read.csv(text=rawData,header=FALSE)
colnames(data) <- colNames    
data %>% gather(.) -> tidyData

tidyData
```

...and the output.

```
> tidyData
         key value
1 Category 1    11
2 Category 2    50
3 Category 3     2
4 Category 4     7
5 Category 5    23
6 Category 6    10
>
```

One can change the column names in the resulting `tidyData` data frame via arguments to `gather()`.